# Aptana on dual monitor with Panels

Tags: eclipse, ide, aptana, panels

In Eclipse, I can undock a panel and move it to my other monitor (making it easy to compare two pages at the same time. However, in Aptana, I can split the window's, but it won't let me pull the panel out to my other monitor. Is there a plugin I can install that will allow me to do this?

**Update**

I have Aptana 3.3.1, and I can detach a panel just fine (the console panel for example), but I want to be able to take a file that is in the editor, and move it to my other screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click *Window -> new Window*. 
You can then close all the unneeded panels in the new window, drag it over to the second screen and drop in your editor(s) there.
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

What version of Aptana are you using? In my 3.3.1, I can detach a panel and drag it to my second screen by right clicking on the panel name and choosing 'Detached' or by just dragging it away from the main window.

Comment: On the latest Aptana this sometimes doesn't work if you move your mouse too quickly. I got it working by holding the mouse button, dragging, and hovering over where to drag it for a few seconds for it to register